# SELECT INSERT no Oracle utilizando sequence nextval e group by

Tags: oracle, select, sql-insert

Bom dia, galera!

Estou tentando fazer um select insert no Oracle utilizando uma SEQUENCE no id, mas está dando erro por conta de um group by no select.

Seque minha SQL:

```
  INSERT INTO SUP_T(ID, DESCRICAO)

  SELECT SEQ_SUP_T.NEXTVAL,TIPO.TIPO
  FROM TB_TIPO_APLICACAO TIPO
  GROUP BY TIPO.TIPO;
```

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

```
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02287: número de seqüência não permitido aqui
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
           here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O oracle não permite que você utilize group by com sequence então você tem que fazer o agrupamento primeiro depois incluir a sequence. Da pra fazer tanto com group by quanto com distinct.

group by:

```
INSERT INTO SUP_T(ID, DESCRICAO)
  SELECT SEQ_SUP_T.NEXTVAL, T.TIPO
    FROM(SELECT TIPO.TIPO FROM TB_TIPO_APLICACAO TIPO group by TIPO.TIPO) T
```

distinct:

```
INSERT INTO SUP_T(ID, DESCRICAO)
  SELECT SEQ_SUP_T.NEXTVAL, T.TIPO
    FROM(SELECT DISTINCT TIPO.TIPO FROM TB_TIPO_APLICACAO TIPO) T
```

espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito.Valeu mesmo, Fernando!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta efetuar a consulta a sequence em uma sub-consulta, desta forma.

A consulta em sequences deve ocorrer sempre no objeto DUAL no Oracle.

**Editado:**
Acredito que esta seja a consulta que vai resultar o que você está esperando com o GROUP BY, considerando que não são usadas clausulas agrupadoras no retorno do seu SELECT (Min, Max, Count, Sum) e também não há condição HAVING.

Segue INSERT alterado:

```
INSERT INTO SUP_T(ID, DESCRICAO)

SELECT (SELECT SEQ_SUP_T.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL) As SEQUENCE, 
       T.TIPO
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT TIPO.TIPO
   FROM TB_TIPO_APLICACAO TIPO
) T
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Bruno. Mas o erro permanece.

Comment: Neste caso você está utilizando GROUP BY em um local onde não faz sentido. Nota-se que será gerado um NEXTVAL para cada linha do seu SELECT, logo o resultado não é o esperado. Vou reformular minha resposta e edito.

Comment: obirgado, no aguardo!